# Haskell: Can I perform several folds over the same lazy list without keeping list in memory?

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation, bigdata

My context is bioinformatics, next-generation sequencing in particular, but the problem is generic; so I will use a log file as an example.

The file is very large (Gigabytes large, compressed, so it will not fit in memory), but is easy to parse (each line is an entry), so we can easily write something like:

```
parse :: Lazy.ByteString -> [LogEntry]
```

Now, I have a lot of statistics that I would like to compute from the log file. It is easiest to write separate functions such as:

```
totalEntries = length
nrBots = sum . map fromEnum . map isBotEntry
averageTimeOfDay = histogram . map extractHour
```

All of these are of the form `foldl' k z . map f`.

The problem is that if I try to use them in the most natural way, like

```
main = do
    input <- Lazy.readFile "input.txt"
    let logEntries = parse input
        totalEntries' = totalEntries logEntries
        nrBots' = nrBots logEntries
        avgTOD = averageTimeOfDay logEntries
    print totalEntries'
    print nrBots'
    print avgTOD
```

This will allocate the whole list in memory, which is not what I want. I want the folds to be done synchronously, so that the cons cells can be garbage collected. If I compute only a single statistic, this is what happens.

I can write a single big function that does this, but it is non-composable code.

Alternatively, which is what I have been doing, I run each pass separately, but this reloads & uncompresses the file each time.

Comment: Why don't you make `logAnalysers :: [(K, Z, F)]` where `K, Z, F` are the types of the functions `k, z, f` in your example? Then it becomes "composable" code, in a way, if you have a single fold that uses the list.

Comment: @dflemstr the intermediate types are not always the same :(

Comment: You *could* do `logAnalysers :: [forall a b c . (b -> c -> b, c, a -> b)]`, which would allow for different types...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This a comment on the comment of sdcvvc referring to this ['beautiful folding' essay](http://squing.blogspot.fr/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html)  It was so cool -- beautiful, as he says -- I couldn't resist adding `Functor` and `Applicative` instances and a few other bits of modernization. Simultaneous folding of, say, `x` `y` and `z` is a straightforward product: `(,,) <$> x <*> y <*> z`. I made a half-gigabyte file of small random ints and it took 10 seconds to give the -- admittedly trivial -- calculation of length, sum and maximum on my rusty laptop.  It doesn't seem to be helped by further annotations, but the compiler could see `Int` was all I was interested in;  the obvious `map read . lines` as a parser led to a hopeless space and time catastrophe so I unfolded with a crude use of `ByteString.readInt`; otherwise it is basically a `Data.List` process.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, BangPatterns #-}

import Data.List (foldl', unfoldr)
import Control.Applicative 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B

main = fmap readInts (B.readFile "int.txt") >>= print . fold allThree
  where allThree = (,,) <$> length_ <*> sum_ <*> maximum_

data Fold b c where  F ::  (a -> b -> a) -> a -> (a -> c) -> Fold b c
data Pair a b = P !a !b

instance Functor (Fold b) where  fmap f (F op x g) = F op x (f . g)

instance Applicative (Fold b) where
  pure c = F const () (const c)
  (F f x c) <*> (F g y c') = F (comb f g) (P x y) (c *** c')
    where comb f g (P a a') b = P (f a b) (g a' b)
          (***) f g (P x y) = f x ( g y)

fold :: Fold b c -> [b] -> c
fold (F f x c) bs = c $ (foldl' f x bs)

sum_, product_ :: Num a => Fold a a
length_ :: Fold a Int
sum_     = F (+) 0 id
product_ = F (*) 1 id
length_  = F (const . (+1)) 0 id
maximum_ = F max 0 id
readInts  = unfoldr $ \bs -> case B.readInt bs of
  Nothing      -> Nothing
  Just (n,bs2) -> if not (B.null bs2) then Just (n,B.tail bs2) 
                                      else Just (n,B.empty)
```

Edit: unsurprisingly, since we have to do with an unboxed type above, and an unboxed vector derived from e.g. a 2G file can fit in memory, this is all twice as fast and somewhat better behaved if it is given the obvious relettering for Data.Vector.Uboxed http://hpaste.org/69270  Of course this isn't relevant where one has types like `LogEntry`  Note though that the `Fold` type and Fold 'multiplication' generalizes over sequential types without revision, thus e.g.  the Folds associated with operations on `Char`s or `Word8`s can be simultaneously folded directly over a ByteString. One must first define a `foldB`, by relettering `fold` to use the `foldl'`s in the various ByteString modules. But the `Fold`s and products of `Fold`s are the same ones you would fold a list or vector of `Char`s or `Word8`s

Answer (score 11):

To process lazy data muiltiple times, in constant space, you can do three things:

- re-build the lazy list from scratch *n* times
- fuse *n* passes into a single sequential fold that does each step, in lock step.
- use `par` to do *n* parallel traversals at the same time

Those are your options. The last one is the coolest :)

Comment: It the last one guaranteed, though? What if one thread is much more computationally intensive?

Comment: It's not guaranteed. You have *n* threads racing along the spine of a shared structure as it is being unfolded. IF one is slow, you may retain more of the structure than you planned.

Comment: Option 2 is the one I'd choose, if possible.  (I think it's even doable generically, regardless of the details of the folds...)

Comment: Note that the iteratee/enumerator style is squarely aimed at this issue, using option 2.

Comment: @JohnL Yes, I also realised that later. I am switching to a conduit based solution.

Comment: I meant to say I had noticed some other bioinformatics people http://biohaskell.org/Libraries were using the `iteratee` library in particular http://biohaskell.org/iteratees There is huge amount of activity on the iteratee-conduit-pipe etc front, of course.

Comment: For option 1, have a look at http://darcs.nomeata.de/ghc-dup/ (which is WIP or rather work-under-refereeing).