# Making a single function work on lists, ByteStrings and Texts (and perhaps other similar representations)

Tags: haskell, text, fold, bytestring, lenses

I'm writing a function that does some searching in a sequence of arbitrary symbols. I'd like to make it generic enough so that it works on lists, `Foldable`s as well on `ByteString`s and `Text`s. Generalizing it to `Foldable` is simple. But how to include `ByteString`s and `Text`s? Sure I could convert `ByteString` into a list and then call my function, but I'd lose all the advantages `ByteString`s.

To have a concrete example let's say we want to make a histogram function:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text as T

type Histogram a = Map a Int

empty :: (Ord a) => Histogram a
empty = Map.empty

histogramStep :: (Ord a) => a -> Histogram a -> Histogram a
histogramStep k = Map.insertWith (+) k 1

histogram :: (Ord a, F.Foldable t) => t a -> Histogram a
histogram = F.foldl (flip histogramStep) empty
```

But since neither `ByteString` nor Text can be `Foldable` (it stores just `Word8`s/`Char`s, not arbitrary elements), I'm stuck with creating more functions that look *exactly* like the one before, just with a different type signatures:

```
histogramBS :: B.ByteString -> Histogram Word8
histogramBS = B.foldl (flip histogramStep) empty

histogramText :: T.Text -> Histogram Char
histogramText = T.foldl (flip histogramStep) empty
```

This is something one does not expect in a functional language like Haskell.

**How to make it generic, to write `histogram` once and for all?**

Comment: You always ask interesting questions because you think deeply about what you're doing and always want to understand more. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution is pretty much what the [ListLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike) package does. There's also the additional package [listlike-instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/listlike-instances-0.2.1) which adds instances for `Text` and `Vector`.

Answer (score 5):

After a while I made a solution myself, but I'm not sure if it could be solved in a better way, or if someone already did this in some library.

I created a type-class with `TypeFamilies` as

```
class Foldable' t where
    type Element t :: *
    foldlE :: (b -> Element t -> b) -> b -> t -> b
    -- other functions could be copied here from Foldable
```

and instances:

```
newtype WrapFoldable f a = WrapFoldable { unwrapFoldable :: f a }
instance (F.Foldable f) => Foldable' (WrapFoldable f a) where
    type Element (WrapFoldable f a) = a
    foldlE f z = F.foldl f z . unwrapFoldable

instance Foldable' B.ByteString where
    type Element B.ByteString = Word8
    foldlE = B.foldl


instance Foldable' T.Text where
    type Element (T.Text) = Char
    foldlE = T.foldl
```

or even better with `FlexibleInstances`:

```
instance (F.Foldable t) => Foldable' (t a) where
    type Element (t a) = a
    foldlE = F.foldl
```

Now I can write (with `FlexibleContexts`):

```
histogram :: (Ord (Element t), Foldable' t) => t -> Histogram (Element t)
histogram = foldlE (flip histogramStep) empty
```

and use it on `Foldable`s, `ByteString`s, `Text`s etc.

- **Is there another (perhaps simpler) way to do it?**
- **Is there some library that addresses this problem (in this way or another)?**

Answer (score 5):

You might consider objectifying folds themselves:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Data.List (foldl', unfoldr)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Word
type Histogram a = Map.Map a Int

empty :: (Ord a) => Histogram a
empty = Map.empty
histogramStep :: (Ord a) => Histogram a -> a -> Histogram a
histogramStep h k = Map.insertWith (+) k 1 h 

histogram :: Ord b => Fold b (Histogram b)
histogram = Fold histogramStep empty id

histogramT :: T.Text -> Histogram Char
histogramT = foldT histogram
histogramB :: B.ByteString -> Histogram Word8
histogramB = foldB histogram 
histogramL :: Ord b => [b] -> Histogram b
histogramL = foldL histogram

-- helper library
-- see http://squing.blogspot.fr/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html
-- note existential type
data Fold b c where  Fold ::  (a -> b -> a) -> !a -> (a -> c) -> Fold b c
instance Functor (Fold b) where  fmap f (Fold op x g) = Fold op x (f . g)

foldL :: Fold b c -> [b] -> c
foldL (Fold f x c) bs = c $ (foldl' f x bs)

foldV :: V.Unbox b => Fold b c -> V.Vector b -> c
foldV (Fold f x c) bs = c $ (V.foldl' f x bs)

foldT :: Fold Char t -> T.Text -> t
foldT (Fold f x c) t = c $ (T.foldl' f x t)

foldB :: Fold Word8 t -> B.ByteString -> t
foldB (Fold f x c) t = c $ (B.foldl' f x t)


sum_, product_ :: Num a => Fold a a
sum_ = Fold (+) 0 id
product_ = Fold (*) 1 id

length_ :: Fold a Int
length_ = Fold (const . (+1)) 0 id
maximum_ = Fold max 0 id
```

Comment: While this is probably not the way I'll go, it's very interesting. Definitely it's worth exploring. I also believe that `Fold` is a comonad: `instance Comonad (Fold b) where extract (Fold _ x r) = r x ; duplicate (Fold f x r) = Fold f x (\y -> Fold f y r)`, I briefly checked the laws and seem valid. This could give more ways how to combine its operations.

Comment: Interesting; it is of course Applicative -- this was Rabkin's purpose in discussing it, as is noted in the comments.  I forgot to mention the many posts by the great Conal Elliot e.g. http://conal.net/blog/posts/proofs-for-left-fold-zipping, following Rabkin, which I haven't completely read. He and Rabkin don't seem to make much of the fact at issue here, that the `Fold` type has nothing specially to do with lists, but can be applied to any serial  type X, given a general `foldX` function. I first learned about it from `sdcvvc`'s comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803221

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution using [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package, which has a detailed type-class hierarchy identifying different kind of data structures. Its approach is similar to the one in applicative's answer - it objectifies folds:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.Text as T

import Control.Lens.Fold
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lens as LBS
import qualified Data.Text.Lens as LT

type Histogram a = Map a Int

empty :: (Ord a) => Histogram a
empty = Map.empty

histogramStep :: (Ord a) => a -> Histogram a -> Histogram a
histogramStep k = Map.insertWith (+) k 1

-- Histogram on anything that can be folded into `a`:

histogram :: (Ord a) => Fold c a -> c -> Histogram a
histogram f = foldlOf f (flip histogramStep) empty

-- Specializations are simple:

histogramF :: (Ord a, F.Foldable t) => t a -> Histogram a
histogramF = histogram folded

histogramBS :: B.ByteString -> Histogram Word8
histogramBS = histogram LBS.bytes

histogramText :: T.Text -> Histogram Char
histogramText = histogram LT.text
```