# How to define foldM using foldr/foldl (if it is possible)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, fold

I wanted to make a generic function that folds over a wide range of inputs (see [Making a single function work on lists, ByteStrings and Texts (and perhaps other similar representations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857615/making-a-single-function-work-on-lists-bytestrings-and-texts-and-perhaps-other)). As [one answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857865/1333025), the [ListLike](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ListLike-3.1.6) is just for that. Its [FoldableLL](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ListLike/3.1.6/doc/html/Data-ListLike-FoldableLL.html) class defines an abstraction for anything that is foldable. However, I need a monadic fold. So I need to define `foldM` in terms of `foldl`/`foldr`.

So far, my attempts failed. I tried to define

```
foldM'' :: (Monad m, LL.FoldableLL full a) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> full -> m b
foldM'' f z = LL.foldl (\acc x -> acc >>= (`f` x)) (return z)
```

but it runs out of memory on large inputs - it builds a large unevaluated tree of computations. For example, if I pass a large text file to

```
main :: IO ()
main = getContents >>= foldM'' idx 0 >> return ()
  where
    -- print the current index if 'a' is found
    idx !i 'a' = print i >> return (i + 1)
    idx !i _   =            return (i + 1)
```

it eats up all memory and fails.

I have a feeling that the problem is that the monadic computations are composed in a wrong order - like `((... >>= ...) >>= ...)` instead of `(... >>= (... >>= ...))` but so far I didn't find out how to fix it.

---

**Workaround:** Since `ListLike` exposes `mapM_`, I constructed `foldM` on `ListLike`s by wrapping the accumulator into the state monad:

```
modifyT :: (Monad m) => (s -> m s) -> StateT s m ()
modifyT f = get >>= \x -> lift (f x) >>= put

foldLLM :: (LL.ListLike full a, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> full -> m b
foldLLM f z c = execStateT (LL.mapM_ (\x -> modifyT (\b -> f b x)) c) z
```

While this works fine on large data sets, it's not very nice. And it doesn't answer the original question, if it's possible to define it on data that are just `FoldableLL` (without `mapM_`).

Comment: why not use `foldM` from `Control.Monad` ? Also use the strict version `foldl'` instead of `foldl`.

Comment: @Satvik Because I need it to define not only for list but for anything [FoldableLL](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ListLike/3.1.6/doc/html/Data-ListLike-FoldableLL.html) which only exposes different kinds of pure folds, not the monadic ones. My bad, I didn't make it clear in the post - I've corrected the type signature.

Comment: To compose the computations in the reverse order, use `foldr` instead of `foldl`.

Comment: @dave4420 I tried that too but doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the goal is to reimplement `foldM` using either `foldr` or `foldl`. Which one should it be? We want the input to be processed lazily and allow for infinte lists, this rules out `foldl`. So `foldr` is it going to be.

So here is the definition of `foldM` from the standard library.

```
foldM             :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
foldM _ a []      =  return a
foldM f a (x:xs)  =  f a x >>= \fax -> foldM f fax xs
```

The thing to remember about `foldr` is that its arguments simply replace `[]` and `:` in the list (`ListLike` abstracts over that, but it still serves as a guiding principle).

So what should `[]` be replaced with? Clearly with `return a`. But where does `a` come from? It won’t be the initial `a` that is passed to `foldM` – if the list is not empty, when `foldr` reaches the end of the list, the accumulator should have changed. So we replace `[]` by a function that takes an accumulator and returns it in the underlying monad: `\a -> return a` (or simply `return`). This also gives the type of the thing that `foldr` will calculate: `a -> m a`.

And what should we replace `:` with? It needs to be a function `b -> (a -> m a) -> (a -> m a)`, taking the first element of the list, the processed tail (lazily, of course) and the current accumulator. We can figure it out by taking hints from the code above: It is going to be `\x rest a -> f a x >>= rest`. So our implementation of `foldM` will be (adjusting the type variables to match them in the code above):

```
foldM'' :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
foldM'' f z list = foldr (\x rest a -> f a x >>= rest) return list z
```

And indeed, now your program can consume arbitrary large input, spitting out the results as you go.

We can even prove, inductively, that the definitions are semantically equal (although we should probably do coinduction or take-induction to cater for infinite lists).

We want to show

```
foldM f a xs = foldM'' f a xs
```

for all `xs :: [b]`. For `xs = []` we have

```
  foldM f a []
≡ return a     -- definition of foldM
≡ foldr (\x rest a -> f a x >>= rest) return [] a -- definition of foldr
≡ foldM'' f a [] -- definition of foldM''
```

and, assuming we have it for `xs`, we show it for `x:xs`:

```
  foldM f a (x:xs)
≡ f a x >>= \fax -> foldM f fax xs --definition of foldM
≡ f a x >>= \fax -> foldM'' f fax xs -- induction hypothesis
≡ f a x >>= \fax -> foldr (\x rest a -> f a x >>= rest) return xs fax -- definition of foldM''
≡ f a x >>= foldr (\x rest a -> f a x >>= rest) return xs -- eta expansion
≡ foldr (\x rest a -> f a x >>= rest) return (x:xs) -- definition of foldr
≡ foldM'' f a (x:xs) -- definition of foldM''
```

Of course this equational reasoning does *not* tell you anything about the performance properties you were interested in.

Comment: I want exactly what `foldM` does on lists. So a left fold, no for infinite lists. I'll try to replace `idx` with something more meaningful.

Comment: `foldM` does work on infinite list, so the monadic action is left-folded while the accumulator is right-folded. Or something like that :-)

Comment: @PetrPudlák: a left fold on a list can also be written as a right fold: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldl_as_foldr