# Is there a Functor instance for Data.Text?

Tags: haskell, text, functor

As [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.3.1/doc/html/Data-Text.html#v%3amap) exists for `Data.Text` it could be an instance of `Functor` which would be useful when writing generic algorithms that work on `String`s and `Text`s. Is there a reason why no such instance exists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, because a `Functor` has to be a general 'container', and `Text` can only contain `Char`.

Comment: Ah damn ... now that you say that I think I might have asked a very similar question before :)

Answer (score 5):

A more general explanation in addition to augustss answer: a `Functor` `F` must have kind `* -> *` so as to provide a mapping `a -> F a`, but the kind of `Text` is `*`

Answer (score 2):

`Text` can't be an instance of `Functor` for the reason already given. But there is a type class called [`ListLike`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ListLike/4.0.0/doc/html/Data-ListLike.html), which is targeted for data types that have only one kind of elements, such as `Text` can contain only `Char`s. With `ListLike` you can write a function that works on `String` as well as `Text`.

It's defined using functional dependencies as

```
class (FoldableLL full item, Monoid full) => ListLike full item | full -> item where
    -- ...
    map :: ListLike full' item' => (item -> item') -> full -> full'
    -- ...
```

which allows you to map elements using a function and create another (possibly different) `ListLike` from them. (However note that some of `ListLike`'s operations can be inefficient, so be careful if you'll be using them for large data.)

See [Making a single function work on lists, ByteStrings and Texts (and perhaps other similar representations)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12857615/1333025).