# Why is there no typeclass for container-types?

Tags: haskell

I found out that some containers have a very similar function set. List, Set, Sequence, Text and Bytestrings for example. I wonder why they don't use one or more common typeclasses.

Comment: Actually they do. But the list of "common typeclasses" is usually limited to `Monoid`, `Functor` and, sometimes, `ListLike`. I think that is because other classes don't exist or are not common enough.

Comment: By the way, look at the `lens` package for a library that has found a way to abstract over all of those. But it doesn't do it with new typeclasses, the way you might think..

Comment: @Yuras - containers should support Traversable and Foldable (or have a good reason for not doing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there are, see question [Making a single function work on lists, ByteStrings and Texts (and perhaps other similar representations)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12857615/1333025), which is almost a duplicate of yours.

The main reason for being in a separate package is probably that it needs a language extension - either functional dependencies or type families. We have to somehow say that `Text` can contain only `Char`s, `ByteString` can contain only `Word8`s, `[]` can contain any type, and `Set` can contain only instances of `Ord`.

Answer (score 9):

What common function set do they have? AFAICS, only the ability to combine multiple containers into a single one, and to generate empty containers. And behold, indeed they're all `Monoid`, which offers exactly that interface!

You can't really do anything else with all of these since some are polymorphic, some monomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphic containers like list, [Sequence](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html), [Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html) and [Map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Lazy.html) are instances of [Functor](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Control-Monad.html#t%3aFunctor), [Foldable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Foldable.html) and [Traversable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-Traversable.html) typeclasses.

For [Set](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Set.html) you have only [Foldable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Foldable.html), as Ord instance makes it impossible to define others (you can define `fmap` ([Data.Set.map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Set.html#v%3amap)) which would obey functor laws, but it's signature would require Ord instances on arguments).

As mentioned before, Text and Bytestring can be instances of similar typeclasses defined, but you will need either functional dependencies or type families.

Comment: [Set _is_ monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/src/Data-Set-Base.html#line-231): since that class has no polymorphic functions / the contained type is fixed in the instance head, it behaves as a monomorphic container there. — Incidentally, there's even a clever way in which you can [make it Functor/Applicative/Monad](http://copilotco.com/mail-archives/haskell-cafe.2007/msg00051.html), as well; that requires binding the `Ord` instance in a GADT.

Comment: More about Set and Functor: http://dorchard.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/subcategories-in-haskell-exofunctors/